# Open source ERP for a small/medium e-commerce site

Tags: open-source, inventory, enterprise-portal

I am looking around for which would be the best ERP solution for my company that is preferably open source, I looked around a few like:

OpenERP (Now Odoo) but they don't seem very well maintained, I made a test account and even the setting panel was a bit buggy.

I have a Postgres database and would be good if the ERP system can take advantage of that.

EDIT:

In general what I am looking for is an ERP that is able to:

- Keep our stock levels
- Track the statuses of all orders throughout the sales department, the customer service department and the purchasing department.
- The interface with the end users (employees from my company) can interact with it without knowing SQL or coding.
- Connect with our Postgres database which extracts data from our website's backend.

Note: We do not have an ERP in our own backend since it is outsourced to another company, we manage only the content of the website and the loads into the database.

I also don't mind doing some development if necessary, I am just looking for something modest (cheap or free) and solid.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details, then [edit] your question to incorporate some of the improvements learned there. Thanks – and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Izzy, it's tough to recommend a great solution with limited information. That said, I'd suggest checking out xTuple's ERP solution (open source) and the [xTupleCommerce](https://xtuple.com/blog/jfischer/getting-started-videos-xtuplecommerce) solution (open source, built on top Drupal and connects with the ERP in real-time).

Both system's are solid, have a strong community, long roster of customers and there are a lot of resources online. If you go to [xTupleUniversity.com](http://xtupleuniversity.com) you'll find plenty of videos that will help you get an overview of both systems and how they are integrated.

Full disclaimer - I work with xTuple but I'm not a sales guy. My team is building the xTupleCommerce system. I'm speaking from the product & customer-use side rather than sales.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ERPAL for Service Providers](https://www.drupal.org/project/erpal), which is a "distribution" using [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) (version 7). Some more details (from its project page):

> ERPAL is a centralized and web based business management distribution for software developers and service providers. It enables you to manage business processes with ONE smart toolbox that includes all the following features out of the box:
>
> - CRM (contact and activity management)
> - Project management (timetracking, payments, Agil and fixed price, expenses, Gantt charts, requirement management) with Freelancer support
> - Document management and document creation
> - Contract management with recurring invoices
> - Employee management (overtime, holidays, costs)
> - Invoice creation and PDF export
> - Calendars
> - ...and many other features
>
> ERPAL's goal is to have ONE TOOL to consolidate all the different business processes to reduce the time you spend with administration and project controlling. The ERPAL system enables you to manage all your everyday business tasks in one integrated smart solution.

Many more details about it can be found via the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Dolibarr ERP CRM](https://www.dolibarr.org) . It's an Open Source web application with a low learning curve. If you just want to test without installing it on your Linux server, you can try a demo (a small list of demo providers is maintained on the list of [SaaS instant demo](https://saas.dolibarr.org))